# How do I send email from my Gmail account in my Node.js script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, smtp, gmail

```
app.get('/email', function(req,res){
    var emailjs = require('emailjs');
    var email_server = emailjs.server.connect({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        ssl: true,
        tls: true,
        port: "465",
        user:'kateholloway@gmail.com',
        password:'mypassword',
    });

    var h={
        text: 'hey how you doing',
        from: 'Kate Holloway <kateholloway@gmail.com>',
        to: 'someonesemail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'where is your phone'
    };
    var message = emailjs.message.create(h);
    email_server.send(message, function(err,message){
        console.log(err);
        console.log(message);
        res.send('ok');
    });

});
```

Is this the right settings to do it?

The error message I get is:

```
{ [Error: connection has ended] code: 9, smtp: undefined }
```

Note: this code works with my own domain/server. But it doesn't work with Gmail. Therefore, I think my settings for Gmail smtp are incorrect.

Comment: although in my company we don't use node, we do use a lot gmail for emailing. in some cases we detected that port 587 is necessary; see if it can fix your problem.

Comment: Try removing the ssl and port options from email_server. If you just set tls: true, it will figure out the ssl and port settings.

Answer (score 1):

We have used this library with Gmail. We have only set host, user, password and ssl options.
Its working as expected. Try removing other options.